# Loop through solutions of Matlab's 'solve' command

Tags: matlab, struct, solver

I have for example to following Matlab code.

```
A = [1/2 -1 1; -1/6 1/2 -1];
b = [sym('b',[2 1]); 1];
SOL = solve(A*b == zeros(2,1));
```

Now the solution, `SOL`, has two fields `b1` and `b2`. I can access the solutions by typing `SOL.b1` or `SOL.b2`. Now I want to loop through these two solutions. How can I do this? For example `SOL.b(i)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [dynamic field names](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html):

```
for ii = 1:2
    SOL.(['b' num2str(ii)])
    %// do whatever with this
end
```